# How do I show specific category in Recycler view from JSON

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I want to add project data to recyclerview of only specific category.
for example here in my JSON you can see there are 2 projects in cab category, so I want to add this 2 projects only, vice versa if category equals "Truck" so I want to only add all truck category project.

**Here is my JAVA**

```
   @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String category = jsonObject.getString("category_name");

                           //////  /* stuckk here???   if (category.contains("cabs"))*/ /////
                            
                                    JSONArray JsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("projects");

                                    for (int ii = 0; ii < JsonArray.length(); ii++) {
                                        JSONObject jObject = JsonArray.getJSONObject(ii);

                                        p_id = jObject.getString("id");
                                        p_name = jObject.getString("name");
                                     
                                    }

                                ProjectItemModel projectItemModel = new ProjectItemModel(p_id, p_name);
                                ProjectList.add(projectItemModel);                 
                            }

                            mAdapter = new ProjectAdapter(ProjectList);
                            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
                            project_rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                            project_rv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

**Here is my JSON API call**

```
[
    {
        "category_name": "Cabs",
        "category_image": "cab.png",
        "projects": [
            {
                "id": "1002",
                "uid": "SP1001",
                "name": "car1"        
            }
        ]
    },{
        "category_name": "Cabs",
        "category_image": "cab.png",
        "projects": [
            {
                "id": "1003",
                "uid": "SP1003",
                "name": "car2"        
            }
        ]
    },{
        "category_name": "Truck",
        "category_image": "truck.png",
        "projects": [
            {
                "id": "1001",
                "uid": "SP1001",
                "name": "Truck1"        
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

pls help me sort this problem THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in listing the projects

```
 ArrayList<String> categories_to_display=new ArrayList();
public void onResponse(String response) {
    ArrayList<ProjectItemModel> ProjectList = new ArrayList<ProjectItemModel>();
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String category = jsonObject.getString("category_name");

            //////  /* stuckk here???   if (category.contains("cabs"))*/ /////
//                if (category.equalsIgnoreCase("carbs")) {//you could use this for only one category
            if (categories_to_display.contains(category)) {

                JSONArray JsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("projects");

                for (int ii = 0; ii < JsonArray.length(); ii++) {
                    JSONObject jObject = JsonArray.getJSONObject(ii);

//        p_id = jObject.getString("id");
//        p_name = jObject.getString("name");
                    ProjectItemModel projectItemModel = new ProjectItemModel(jObject.getString("id"), jObject.getString("name"));
                    ProjectList.add(projectItemModel);
                }


            }
        }

        mAdapter = new ProjectAdapter(ProjectList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        project_rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        project_rv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

so now Just Add the categories you need to the arraylist categories_to_display then clear the array if you need to sett new categories to check or if its a single category, just use   this line instead of the line below it so comment the line below it and uncomment this  `//                if (category.equalsIgnoreCase("carbs")) {//you could use this for only one category`